# Django Form on a Table

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my HTML I have a Table that looks like this:

```
<table class = 'training'>
    <thead>
        <th>Iterations</th>
        <th>Repetitions</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ iterations }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type ="text"></td>
            <td><input type ="text"></td>
            <td><input type ="text"></td>
            <td><input type ="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the Django-Form File I created a class for "iterations":

```
class IterationForm(forms.Form):
iteration = forms.IntegerField(label= "")
```

And I also added it to the views.py.

Now my Site I got this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td><input id="id_iteration" name="iteration" type="number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I dont understand why this happens because I dont think, that I told Django to add another `<th>` Tag to my Site. Can someone please explaine me this and help me to solve this Problem.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options

Comment: @HiteshDharamdasani I tried it with "{{ form.as_table }}" but Django still add a "<th>" Tag on it.